# All programs start by themselves at the same time

Tags: windows, windows-10, themes, software-conflict

Whenever I switch Windows themes which I have installed from https://www.deviantart.com/, a bunch of programs in the start menu would open up together at the same time by themselves.

Yes, all of the following programs in my screenshot. This also happens when I change Windows theme sounds or any Windows setting. I have no clue on how to fix it.

I think this might be a software conflict.

---

***Edit & Update Question :***

I'm pretty sure the fact that I was using System Transparency, TranslucentTB and many other softwares(StartIsBack, OldNewExplorer,...) caused the conflict though I'm not sure what the real culprit was. The problem doesn't seem to happen in other user accounts so I deleted my current user account to switch to another account and it fixed it.

[image]

Comment: Does this happen when booting Windows in Safe mode?

Comment: Did you notify the creator of the theme?

Comment: @harrymc In safe mode, the problem doesn't seem to occur when changing theme sounds. However, I can't access Theme settings. An error message shows up:  Settings:System Settings.exe-System Error: The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.

Comment: @Gantendo yes I did. I'm using Paranoid Android Windows 10 Themes by niivu: https://www.deviantart.com/niivu/art/Paranoid-Android-Windows-10-Themes-821696974                                                                                                                                           
 and Matte theme: https://www.deviantart.com/kdr3w/art/Matte-758699852

Comment: Does it happen if you uninstall these themes? If it still does, try [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc it didn't do much. Eventually I was able to fix the problem so I posted an update as following.